# How can I implement a whitelist on a specific port using iptables?

Tags: iptables

I'm trying to implement a set of rules using iptables which blocks incoming traffic with a given `dport` by default, but allows incoming traffic if the source IP or MAC address is on a certain whitelist.

So far, I'm only aware of being able to apply a global `DROP` policy to a chain (`INPUT`/`OUTPUT`, etc.), but I'm not sure about how to apply this kind of policy to incoming connections only on a certain port.

Answer (score 4):

From your description, this is a fairly simple problem in iptables. I would approach it in three steps.

Add a new chain for your policy:

```
iptables -N MYCHAIN
```

Define a port list in the `INPUT` chain for the destination port you want to process:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p <protocol, either tcp or udp> -m <again, protocol, match the '-p' switch value> --dport <portnum> -j MYCHAIN
```

What this does is to define the specific ports and then "jumps" to the rules for the named chain (MYCHAIN, in this case).

Now, set up rules in MYCHAIN to allow/deny traffic to the described ports.

```
iptables -A MYCHAIN -s <source_IP> -j ACCEPT
iptables -A MYCHAIN -s <other_source_IP> -j ACCEPT
iptables -A MYCHAIN -j DROP
```

In the last rule, you could, of course, use `REJECT`, instead of `DROP`. The user manual ( `man iptables` ) should show you additional parameters you can use to log or limit the traffic you're seeing. There are also several online tutorials available for more advanced rules.

Comment: [Make that should use REJECT instead of DROP](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~peterb/network/drop-vs-reject)

Comment: Depends on what you're wanting to accomplish: it's certainly an option, as I noted.

Answer (score 0):

Set your default policy. Packets matching none of the below given rules will be dropped by default:

```
iptables -P INPUT DROP
```

Create a custom chain. We are going to pass packets fulfilling given conditions (for example having source address 10.0.0.1) to this chain:

```
iptables -N CUSTOM
```

Accept connections that are already up and accept connections on the loopback interface:

```
iptables -A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
```

Pass new TCP connections from 10.0.0.1 (arriving on interface eth0) to the CUSTOM chain:

```
iptables -s 10.0.0.1 -i eth0 -p tcp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j CUSTOM
```

Append rules to the custom chain that which accept specific ports:

```
iptables -A CUSTOM -p tcp -m multiport --dports 22,80 -j ACCEPT
```